# How to serialize the base class with derived classes

Tags: c#, serialization

.

Hello,

I have this sample code :

```
public class Vehicule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
public class Car : Vehicule
{
    public string Matriculation { get; set; }
}



public class Brand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Renault : Brand
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

If I create this instance :

```
var car = new Car { Name = "Clio", Matriculation = "XXX-XXX", Brand = new Renault { Name = "Renault", Information = "Contact Infos" } };
```

When I serialize this object like that :

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car), new Type[] { typeof(Renault)});
serializer.Serialize(wr, car);
```

I obtain this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Clio</Name>
  <Brand xsi:type="Renault">
    <Name>Renault</Name>
    <Information>Contact Infos</Information>
  </Brand>
  <Matriculation>XXX-XXX</Matriculation>
</Car>
```

But, in my project, I don't have to have informations on derived classes, I would like only elements of base classes from this instance like this :

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicule));
serializer.Serialize(wr, car);
```

The Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Clio</Name>
  <Brand>
    <Name>Renault</Name>
  </Brand>
</Vehicule>
```

Can you please, help me to obtain the good Xml (only with base type Vehicule and Brand) ?

Many thanks

Comment: You can't without some manual work because of the way XML Serializer works. You can either create an instance of your bases and map the values over or look at the answer by RichardOD here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047355/permanently-cast-derived-class-to-base

Comment: Thanks TyCobb for these informations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't magically serialize a derived class as it's base because

> "...Serialization checks type of instance by calling Object.getType()
>   method. This method always returns the exact type of object."

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/809946-how-force-serialize-base-type

The solution here, if you really need to only serialize the base class is to implement the IXmlSerializable interface and create your own custom serializer.

**IXmlSerializable**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

One more thought.  If you can work around the limitation of outputting the extra XML elements, you are able to serialize the derived class using only the base object by either 1) using [XmlIncludeAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the base class to tell it which types to expect or 2) using the [XmlSerializer constructor](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83181d16-a048-44e5-b675-a0e8ef82f5b7/why-do-i-have-to-xmlinclude-derived-classes-in-order-to-serialize?forum=asmxandxml) overload that takes a list of types.

**Edit:**
After thinking about this a little more, a workaround would be that you would add a Clone() method onto your base object, then serialize the clone of the base.

**LinqPad code**:

```
public class Vehicule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public Vehicule Clone()
    {
        return new Vehicule { Name = this.Name, Brand = new Brand { Name = this.Brand.Name } };
    }
}
public class Car : Vehicule
{
    public string Matriculation { get; set; }
}



public class Brand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Renault : Brand
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{   
    var car = new Car { Name = "Clio", Matriculation = "XXX-XXX", Brand = new Renault { Name = "Renault", Information = "Contact Infos" } };
    var vehicle = car as Vehicule;

    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicule));

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false),
        Indent = false,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false
    };

    using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    using(XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings)) {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, vehicle.Clone());
        textWriter.ToString().Dump();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the issues with **inheritance**, and another reason to favor **composition** imho.

I ran into the same issue on a mobile app where I had a `Contact` class that derives from `ContactSummary`.  The repository returns `Contact` instances, but in lots of cases I only wanted the `ContactSummary` going over the wire to save on message sizes and data usage etc.  The default Xml and Json serialisers would only work when the derived class was attributed with the `[KnownType()]` of the base class, but this still meant all those extra properties going over the wire.

Using inheritance it is problematic to achieve a viable solution, and I didn't want to resort to custom serialisers, and if the solution is to pollute the DTO with copy constructors and clone properties, then why not change the DTO to use composition instead?

If you have control over your DTOs, then restructuring them to use **composition** rather than inheritance may be the answer.  In my example it was fairly simple...

```
public class ContactSummary
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public ContactSummary Summary { get; set; }
    // ... other properties here
}
```

In your example, `Car` would need to contain a reference to `Vehicle` not inherit from it - something like...

```
[KnowTypes(typeof(Renault))]
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public string Matriculation { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you want the 'base' type in your example, simply serialise `Car.Vehicle`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got around it by re-mapping the inheriting class into the base class using AutoMapper:

```
    MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Inheriting, Base>());
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var baseObj = mapper.Map<Base>(InheritingObj);
```

There is not much you can customize on XmlSerializer out-of-the-box options.