# Json.Net serializes derived class instead of base class in ApiController

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-apicontroller

I am using the MVC ApiController to create an API for my website.

I have a base class `ThinDevice` that contains a subset of information for a `Device`.  In my API I only want to serialize the properties belonging to `ThinDevice` but, despite me casting, and using `ThinDevice` as the return type when I serialize a `Device` it always serializes the entire object

```
[HttpGet]
public ThinDevice Get(string id)
{
    // This returns Device
    var device = this.dataService.GetDevice(id);

    if (device != null)
    {
        // I only want to serialize properties in ThinDevice
        return device as ThinDevice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that expected?

Comment: I would expect that it would serialize based on my return type.  Even if my expectation is wrong I'd like to know how to do it :)

Comment: may be you change the return type of `dataService.GetDevice(id)`. because derived types might contain values for some base class properties, may be  to make the object graph complete , the `serialization` is considering the derived type.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is expected. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047355/permanently-cast-derived-class-to-base) for details.

**Option 1:**
I would suggest to create an instance of `ThinDevice` manually, or if this class is abstract, then itroduce some separate model for the response.

Sample:

```
public class ThinDevice
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class Device1 : ThinDevice
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ThinDevice Get()
{
    return GetDeviceResponse(new Device1 { A = "A", B = "B" });
}

private ThinDevice GetDeviceResponse<T>(T device) where T : ThinDevice
{
    return new ThinDevice
    {
        A = device.A
    };
}
```

This code is not very nice (especially if you have complex object structure).

**Option 2:** You can implement custom JSON and XML serialization that will include only data that you want, but this can be difficult.